# What does segmentation fault mean in this context?

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, pthreads

I am working on a program that schedules a number of non-interactive jobs in the background based on a number given by the user. Afterwards, the user is meant to use keywords such as "submit" followed by a program and arguments and "showjobs", in order to interact. Each job is put into a queue and results of the "submit" keyword or any errors are put into files. For whatever reason, I keep receiving a segmentation fault and I can't quite pinpoint the exact issue with my code. I was hoping to get a second pair of eyes and a little more understanding as to what a segmentation fault means in the context of my code?

After compiling and running I receive a Segmentation fault at this point:

```
Enter command> Segmentation fault
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "queue.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

// global variables
int P; 
int job_counter = 1;
queue *q;

pthread_mutex_t counter_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *addThread(void *arg) {
    int status = 0;
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_mutex);
        char *job = queue_delete(q);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_mutex);

        // tokenization
        char *path = strtok(job, " ");
        char *argument = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
       
        // chid process
        if (pid == 0) {
            char output[1064];
            char error[1064];

            snprintf(output, sizeof(output), "%d.out", job_counter);
            snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "%d.err", job_counter);

            freopen(output, "w", stdout);
            freopen(error, "w", stderr);

            execlp(path, argument, NULL);   
            perror("Something wrong with exec");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // parent process
        else if (pid > 0) {
            job_counter++;
        }

        // put waiting outside of parent process that way whole program isn't halted
        while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            sleep(2);
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                printf("Child exited.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Child did not terminate properly.\n");
            }
        }
        job_counter--;
    }
}

void showJobs() {
    queue_display(q);
}

/* Function that monitors P and number of jobs in the queue in order to determine whether suser's "submit" command
should be executed. Allows for main function to continue running and asking for user input, while executing jobs. */
void *runThread(void *arg) {
    while (true) {
        if (job_counter < P && q->count > 0 && q != NULL) {
            pthread_t thread;
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, addThread, NULL);
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char command[BUFSIZ];

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Missing an argument! Make sure an executable AND an integer is given.");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // holds the argument, P, given by user
    P = atoi(argv[1]);

    // create queue
    q = createQueue(P);

    pthread_t thread;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runThread, NULL);

    while ((strcmp(command, "stop")) != 0) {
        printf("Enter command> ");
        fgets(command, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(command, "submit") == 0) {
            printf("Job %d added to queue.", job_counter);
            char *position;
            // if command given by user contains the word submit in it
            if ((position = strstr(command, "submit")) != NULL) {
                if (position == command) {
                    char command[BUFSIZ];
                    // removes the word submit as well as the space following it, hence the extra + 1 following strlen()
                    memmove(command, position + strlen("submit") + 1, strlen(position + strlen("submit") + 1) + 1);
                }

                queue_insert(q, command, "Waiting");
                job_counter++;
            }
        }

        else if (strcmp(command, "showjobs") == 0) {
            showJobs();
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "stop") == 0) {
            printf("Exiting . . .");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the queue header file and .c file
queue.h

```
/* Header file for the simple circular queue example */
#ifndef __QUEUE_H__
#define __QUEUE_H__

typedef struct _queue {
    int size;    /* maximum size of the queue */
    char **buffer; /* queue buffer */
    int start;   /* index to the start of the queue */
    int end;     /* index to the end of the queue */
    int count;   /* no. of elements in the queue */
    char *status; /* added a status variable to keep track of thread status/child status*/
    int tid;    /* added a thread id*/
} queue;

queue *queue_init(int n);
int queue_insert(queue *q, char *item, char *status);
int queue_delete(queue *q);
void queue_display(queue *q);
void queue_destroy(queue *q);

#endif
```

queue.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

/* Function that returns a pointer to a queue structure, queue*; Pointer allows the function 
    to allocate memory dynamically using malloc and return the address of the allocated memory;
    Initializes queue structure */
queue *createQueue(int n) {
    queue *q = (queue *)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q->size = n;
    q->buffer = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    q->start = 0;
    q->end = 0;
    q->count = 0;
    q->status = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);

    return q;
}

/* insert an item into the queue, update the pointers and count, and
   return the no. of items in the queue (-1 if queue is null or full) */
int queue_insert(queue *q, char *item, char *status) {
    if ((q == NULL) || (q->count == q->size))
       return -1;

    
    q->buffer[q->end % q->size] = (char *)malloc((sizeof atoi(item) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(q->buffer[q->end % q->size], item);
    q->buffer[q->end % q->size] = item;
    q->status = status; 
    q->end = (q->end + 1) % q->size;
    q->count++;

    return q->count;
}

/* delete an item from the queue, update the pointers and count, and 
   return the item deleted (-1 if queue is null or empty) */
int queue_delete(queue *q) {
    if ((q == NULL) || (q->count == 0))
       return -1;

    char *x = q->buffer[q->start];
    q->start = (q->start + 1) % q->size;
    q->count--;

    return x;
}

/* display the contents of the queue data structure */
void queue_display(queue *q) {
    int i;
    if (q != NULL && q->count != 0) {
        printf("queue has %d elements, start = %d, end = %d\n", 
               q->count, q->start, q->end);
        printf("queue contents: ");
        for (i = 0; i < q->count; i++)
            printf("%s, %s ", q->buffer[(q->start + i) % q->size], q->status);
        printf("\n");
    } else
        printf("queue empty, nothing to display\n");
}

/* delete the queue data structure */
void queue_destroy(queue *q) {
    free(q->buffer);
    free(q);
}
```

Comment: What is this meant to do? `command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';`

Comment: @pmacfarlane I meant for that line to be used to replace \n with the null terminator. I got an error previously out of nowhere because of some issue with that.

Comment: See [Removing trailing newline from `fgets()` input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/15168)

Comment: Your queue implementation cannot be used in the multithread program as you do not have any synchronization mechanisms there. You need mutexes, cond variables and signals. Check https://github.com/chrismerck/rpa_queue for example

Comment: @Florence `strlen()` doesn't measure up to a newline, it measures up to the terminating `\0`. So you've either already got a terminating `\0` (and don't need to add one), or you don't, in which case you'd need to use something other than `strlen()` to find the end of the string.